# Trying to Outtput mat-grid-tile, and the data provided by Coud-Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to output the data porvided at the same time as mat-grid-tile is rendered

Im using Angular *ngForOf to reach this

```
<mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="500px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards | async; let produto of produtos | async" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows" >  
      <mat-card class="product-cards" >
        <img matCardImage src="{{produto.imageURL}}">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{produto.nomeProduto}}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>{{produto.preco | currency:'AOA':'symbol-narrow':'2.2-4'}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
            {{produto.descricao}}
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions align="end">
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClick" matTooltip="Favorito">
            <mat-icon class="mat-18">favorite</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClick" matTooltip="Adicionar ao carrinho">
            <mat-icon class="mat-18">add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Ver detalhes" routerLink="{{produto.id}}">
            <mat-icon class="mat-18">visibility</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClick" matTooltip="Editar">
            <mat-icon class="mat-18">edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

this is the line of code that iam trying to reach this aproach:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards | async; let produto of produtos | async">
```

but is outputing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second let produto of produtos | async is not read because *ngFor doesn't work that way. Check [this.](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngfor) Try to combine it with *ngIf. 
Also, if you put second *ngFor inside mat-grid-tile like this:

```
 <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">  
  <mat-card class="product-cards" *ngFor="let produto of produtos | async" >
   ...
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

you will get your tiles as desired but each tile content will be filled with entire array.